# Como puedo hacer compraciones entre varios numeros?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo este algoritmo. Por favor ignoren las variables ya que lo estoy tomando como un ejemplo para después modificarlo.

Mi punto es que en el `if` quiero hacer una comparación, si el usuario ingresa un número, por ejemplo entre 1 y 5, pero no me sale, quisiera que me ayudaran con esto por favor.

Por ejemplo, si un usuario está entre 1 y 5 vive en la tierra, caso contrario entre 6 y 12 en Marte y caso contrario no vive en el sistema solar. Solo quiero saber como poner esa comparación por favor.

```js
var usuario = prompt("¿Cuales son las calorias consumidas?")
var peso = parseInt(usuario);
var planeta = prompt("Elige tu planeta 1 es Marte, 2 es Júpiter");
var g_tierra = 9.8;
var g_marte = 3.7;
var g_jupiter = 24.8;
var peso_final;
if(planeta == 1)
      {
         peso_final = peso * g_marte / g_tierra;
         peso_final = parseInt(peso_final);
         document.write(" Tu peso en Marte es <strong> " + peso_final + " Kilos </strong>");
       } 
else if(planeta == 2)
       {
          peso_final = peso * g_jupiter / g_tierra;
          peso_final = parseInt(peso_final);
          document.write(" Tu peso en Júpiter es <strong> " + peso_final + " Kilos </strong>");
        }
else
        {
           document.write("No estas siendo muy honesto.");
        }
peso_final = parseInt(peso_final);
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifícalo según necesites, seria algo así:

```
numeroIngresado = 1; // Aquí reemplazas por el input donde el usuario ingresa el número
if (numeroIngresado >= 1 && numeroIngresado <= 5)
    alert('Vive en la Tierra');
else if (numeroIngresado >= 6 && numeroIngresado <= 12)
    alert('Vive en Marte');
else
    alert('No vive en el sistema solar');
```

Saludos.